# Regex giving extra output in java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

My code is like:

```
String try1 = " how abcd is a lake 3909 Witmer Road Niagara Falls NY 14305 and our adress is 120, 5th cross, 1st main, domlur, Bangalore 50071 nad 420, Fanboy Lane, NewYark, AS 12345";
String add1="( \\b+[0-9]{3,5}[, ]* (.*)[, ]* (.*)[, ]* [a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{5})";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(add1);
Matcher m = p.matcher(try1);
if(m.find())
{ 
    System.out.println("Address ======> " + m.group());
}
else System.out.println("Address ======>Not found ");
```

I want only US addresses in output:

```
[(3909 Witmer Road Niagara Falls NY 14305) and (420, Fanboy Lane, NewYark, AS 12345)]
```

but it's outputting like this:

```
(3909 Witmer Road Niagara Falls NY 14305 and our adress is 120, 5th cross, 1st main, domlur, Bangalore 50071 nad 420, Fanboy Lane, NewYark, AS 12345)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regex a bit more like this:

```
"(\\b[0-9]{3,5},? [A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+,?)* [a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{5})"
```

The `[A-Za-z]+,?` part allows only letters (and not numbers).

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/nG5vP7).

Comment: this will give only one address of US. but sting contains 2 addresses... i want both in output.. and number of addresses may increase as string will b changed.

Comment: @AnkitKumar You have to use a `while` loop. [See working demo](http://ideone.com/uoglRL).

Comment: @AnkitKumar You're welcome :) You can mark my answer as accepted if it helped (and this will mark your question as solved as well).

Answer (score 0):

The * operator is greedy, so it matches as many characters as it can. In your expression, the [a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{5} part that matches the zip code and state matches the very last ZIP and state in the input, because the .* patterns you have earlier in the expression, expand to as many characters as they can.

Try changing the `.`s to `[^0-9]` so that it matches anything except digits.

Comment: ([^0-9][, ]* (.*)[, ]* (.*)[, ]* [a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{5})

Comment: You did not change the dots as I asked you. Change all the (.)* to [^0-9]*

Comment: Also, don't change the start, leave it as \\b+[0-9]{3,5}[, ]*

Comment: okay... i tried like this ([0-9]{3,5}[, ]* ([^0-9]*)[, ]* ([^0-9]*)[, ]* [a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{5})  .... but its giving only one address... but input string conatains 2 US addresses.